# String length differ in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox

I have a string with special characters. When i input that string in a textbox in FF it shows length is 91 while the same in IE shows 92. 
String is

> *ø?Ø)ô?­ðCYà?ðÁú­AÖ8Û??#Æñ?U'ÈÊ³?
>   ¸¦eWÔ?{>&ÜÑ@?á¶W¥:éÜy#¼Tmòx£­fÏû?"JÚlRWG?Â

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
function showLength(){
alert(document.getElementById('txt').value.length)
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea rows="5" cols="30" id="txt"></textarea><input type="button" onclick="showLength()" value="show"/>
</body>
</html>
```

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nwLsds5m/1/) for test.

Comment: Chrome = 76 characters

Comment: @modiX The snippet will trim the `string`, so snippet is not good to demo here. rolled back.

Comment: That string has a carriage return in it. Is that how your entering it into the textarea? or have you just formatted it for the question?

Comment: I've create the jsfiddle and attach to question, however, `chrome 44.0.2403.125 m (64-bit)` and `IE 11.0.9600.17914` here both show `91`.

Comment: Firefox will count the newline as one character, while Internet Explorer – as two characters.

Comment: To get rid of any unwanted newline characters you could use --------someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");

Comment: Does this problem exist with regular characters as well (with the newline), or just special characters?